# getting img element from known source

Tags: javascript

say I have an img tag as follows in a web page

```
<img src = "https://www.google.com">
```

is there a way for me to get this element by src in javascript? so something like document.elementFromSrc() or something like that? The goal after getting this img element is to find the x and y coordinate and such

Answer (score 3):

If you're unable to add an id, you could do:

```
var allImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var target;
for(var i = 0, max = allImages.length; i < max; i++)
    if (allImages[i].src === "https://www.google.com"){
       target = allImages[i];
       break;
    }
```

But ideally you would just add an id to this img, and then get it with `document.getElementById`

Comment: can you also tell me how can I add an id to an existing element? say I have var img already pointing to the img element, how do I add an id?

Comment: @adit - I don't think you're supposed to add an id to an element after the page has been rendered.  Just add it to the markup, or if that's not an option, add a new **class** to the image, which you could later grab with getElementsByClassName

Comment: @adit: `element.id = value;` will do. I suggest to read about JavaScript and DOM at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference).

Comment: @Felix - ids can be changed dynamically?  I thought that was a no-no

Comment: @adit - I meant change `<img src='' >` to `<img id='newId' src='' >`

Comment: @Adam: Why should it? You can always create new elements and add them to the DOM later. You can also change existing IDs. I have never heard that one should avoid it and it worked so far for me. That said, it could still be that I'm wrong.

Comment: @adit - as Felix says, if you somehow can't add an id to your markup, and somehow already have this image saved in a JavaScript variable, you can assign a new id directly to its `id` property

Comment: I mean I am adding id's just for the purpose of getting the image quickly. I have no access towards the html string I am getting

Comment: @adit - then yeah, add an id as Felix says

Comment: might be a bit off topic, but is there a max limit of string length that an id of an html can have?

Answer (score 2):

Don't loop over all images in the document. Use query selector which uses regex to match the query string. 
Try this: 
 `document.querySelector('[src*="https://www.google.com""]')`

PS jquery has 94kb minified file size. Please don't include it unless there's a requirement.

Comment: It works! jQuery isn't always the best solution! Sure when my page doesn't need it for other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. You can iterate ([`for` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)) over all `img` elements (using [`getElementsByTagName` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)) and compare the `src` attribute or property against the URL you are searching for.

Comment: how do I do this then, iterating through all img elements?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
var offset = $('img[src="http://www.google.com"]').offset();
```

This gives you the x and y coordinates within the document. See documentation for [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to get an element by an attribute value (at least, not a widely supported one, although XPath-like selectors might be common soon).  You can do a quick filter like so:

```
function getElementsByAttributeName(tagName, attributeName, attributeValue) {
  var i, n, objs=[], els=document.getElementsByTagName(tagName), len=els.length;
  for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    n = els[i][attributeName];
    if (n && (n==attributeValue)) {
      objs.push(els[i]);
    }
  }
  return objs;
}
getElementsByAttributeName('img', 'src', 'http://www.google.com'); // => [<a>]
```